# In the following problems, let $K$ be the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $F$. Determine Gal$(K/ F)$ and find all the intermediate subfields of $K/F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

In the following problems, let $K$ be the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $F$.
Determine Gal$(K/ F)$ and find all the intermediate subfields of $K/F$.

(a) $F = \mathbb{Q}$ and $f (x) = x^4 - 7$.

(b) $F = \mathbb{F_5}$ and $f(x) = x^4 - 7$.

(c) $F = \mathbb{Q}$ and $f (x) = x^5 - 2$.

(d) $F = \mathbb{F_2}$ and $f(x) = x^6 + 1$.

(e) $F = \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x) = x^8 - 1$.

My attempt: (a) $f (x) = x^4 - 7=(x^2-\sqrt{7})(x^2+\sqrt{7})=(x-\sqrt[4]{7})(x+\sqrt[4]{7})(x-i\sqrt[4]{7})(x+i\sqrt[4]{7})$ so $K=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[4]{7})$ so $|\text{Gal}(K/F)|=8$ so $\text{Gal}(K/L)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_4$ so $\mathbb{Q}(i), \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{7}), \mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt[4]{7})$ are intermediate field.

This is OK? Any suggestions to solve the rest?

Comment: Don't you think it is $D_8$ instead of $C_2 \times C_4$ ? How many subgroups does it have ?

Comment: @reuns why?   4.?

Comment: Look at the automorphisms, it is not an abelian group (affine group over $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$). $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[4]{7})/\mathbb{Q}$ has more than $4$ proper subextensions thus its Galois group has more than proper $4$ subgroups.

Comment: For example $\sqrt7$ is an element of $K=\Bbb{Q}(i,\root4\of7)$. Do you see why? Yet fields like $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt7)$ and $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$ are missing from your list.

Comment: But, to have any hope of solving parts (a) and (c) you need to exhibit the actual automorphisms (or, at the very least a generating set of them). The remaining cases fall into families, where a textbook answer is available.

Comment: The Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{a}, \zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q}$  is $\{  \zeta_n^b\sqrt[n]{a} \mapsto \zeta_n^{cb+d}\sqrt[n]{a}, \gcd(n,c) = 1\} \cong \text{Aff}_1(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$. @JyrkiLahtonen Do you see a way, with $x^n-a\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ irreducible, to enumerate the subgroups, or the subfields ?

Comment: @reuns Probably somebody can say a lot about it, but I always do it case-by-case. user402543, a quick way of seeing that the Galois group $G$ of $x^4-7$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ cannot be abelian is the following: One of the intermediate fields is $\Bbb{Q}(\root4\of7)$. But, that intermediate field is obviously not Galois. Therefore the subgroup $H\le G$ corresponding to it cannot be normal. Therefore $G$ cannot be abelian.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/86992/11619).